# Http response with all headers required to allow CORS not working

Tags: http, cors, asp.net-core-2.0

I apparently included all headers required to enable CORS but I am still not getting a successful response.

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0. This is the response.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, content- type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Content-Type    
text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date    
Sat, 19 Jan 2019 18:55:42 GMT
Server  
Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding   
chunked
X-Powered-By    
ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles   
=?UTF-8?B?QzpcTG9qYUFTUENvcmVcTG9qYVxMb2phXGNvcnM=?=
```

I am setting the headers like this in an action:

```
[Route("cors")]
public string IncrementarVisualizacao()
{
    Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS");
    Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, content-type");
    Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

    return "Ok";

}
```

Comment: Yes, it's an Angular issue. I've tried to use  jquery and it's working pefectly. I am using Angular 7.

Comment: This doc might help you - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: When I say Angular. I mean something related to how the request is being made. Not that's Angular's fault.

Answer (score 0):

It was the way the request was being made.

I changed this:

```
 this.client.get('http://localhost:5000/endpoint').subscribe(

      data => {
        console.log(data);

      }

    );
```

To this:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  })};

this.client.get('http://localhost:5000/endpoint', httpOptions).subscribe(

  data => {
    console.log(data);

  }

);
```

Make sure the return type of your server response is the one expected by HttpClient.